# Ruby Displaying objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails

UPDATE

my show function

```
def show
@contact = Contact.find(params[:id])
@data = Register.all :include => {:session =>[:term, :course]}  , :conditions => ["contact_id = ?", params[:id]]
respond_to do |format|
  format.html # show.html.erb
  format.xml  { render :xml => @contact }
end
```

end

Models

```
class Register < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :session
 belongs_to :contact
end

class Session < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :term  
 belongs_to :course
 has_many :registers
 has_many :contacts, :through => :registers
end
```

Hi,

I am kind of new to ruby on rails. I want to display the following -

```
- !ruby/object:Register 
attributes: 
 created_at: 2010-06-20 11:39:06
 updated_at: 2010-06-20 11:39:06
 session_id: "32"
 contact_id: "601"
 id: "1"
attributes_cache: {}

session: !ruby/object:Session 
attributes: 
  created_at: 2010-06-19 10:16:13
  term_id: "26"
  updated_at: 2010-06-19 10:16:13
  id: "32"
  course_id: "4"
attributes_cache: {}

course: !ruby/object:Course 
  attributes: 
    created_at: 2010-05-30 14:36:24
    updated_at: 2010-05-30 14:36:28
    course_name: Beginner
    id: "4"
    course_type: Running
  attributes_cache: {}

term: &id001 !ruby/object:Term 
  attributes: 
    number: "1"
    start_date: "2010-06-19"
    created_at: 2010-06-19 10:16:13
    updated_at: 2010-06-19 10:16:13
    id: "26"
  attributes_cache: {}
```

I think I'm doing it wrong

```
    <% @data.Register.each do |c| %>
    <tr>
        <td><%=h c.Term.number %></td>
        <td><%=h c.Course.course_name %></td>
   </tr>
   <% end %>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Ruby on Rails convention is that classes are capitalized, instances of a class are not.

If a model Registration includes a declaration

```
has_one term
```

Then you'd access the term by using

```
registration = Registration.find xxx  # get an instance of the Registration model
registration.term # access the associated term model
                  # do not use registration.Term
```

So...

1) You need to show us your controller code. And your ActiveRecord class files--have you properly defined the relationships using belongs_to, has_many declarations?

2) Your sw should be more like:

```
# Controller
def show
   # Shows all the registrations for person_id
   # args: params['person_id']
   @registrations = Register.find_all_by_person_id(params['person_id'].to_i_
end

# View 

<% @registrations.each do |r| %>
<tr>
    <td><%=h r.term.number %></td>
    <td><%=h r.course.course_name %></td>
</tr>
<% end %>
```

ADDED

Also, be very careful about naming a model "session" -- the potential problem is that CGI sessions may be stored into the model Session if db-backed sessions are turned on.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have added my controller method and some of my model code.

Yes the relationships work, I think I am doing my find wrong.

Comment: Look in your development.log to see if the find's sql is what you want. Also, should probably be: @contact = Contact.find(params[:id].to_i)

Comment: Thanks, I will play around with it.